# scope of a variable in python for this question

Tags: python

I don't know why, but I am getting value of scope as final as 0 even len(s) as zero in the last line of countfrequency(s) function.

```
import collections

def countfrequency(s):
    final = 0
    flag = 1
    d = dict(collections.Counter(s))
    for item in d:
        if d[item] <= k:
            flag = 0
    if flag == 1:                  #Here
        final = max(final, len(s))
    print(final)


s = "ababbc"
k = 2
for x in range(len(s)):
    for y in range(1, len(s)):
        countfrequency(s[x:y + 1])
```

Comment: Your loops are such that you might be passing empty strings to the function. There's no problem of scope in the code?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of 2 reasons :

1. Value of flag is 0 at last so it wont change the value of final
2. Length function takes object as a parameter and when unchanged it gives 0

So you can can either make flag 1 so that control goes inside if condition or print the value of len(s) out side the if condition

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer posted by shaktiraj jadeja, the modified code is as follows:

```
import collections

def countfrequency(s, k):
    final = 0
    flag = 0
    d = dict(collections.Counter(s))
    # print(d)
    for item in d:
        if d[item] > k:
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 1:                  #Here
        # print("Inside:", final, len(s))
        final = max(final, len(s))
    print(final)


s = "ababbc"
k = 2
for x in range(len(s)):
    for y in range(1, len(s)):
        # print(s[x:y])
        countfrequency(s[x:y + 1], k)
```

Comment: you changed the meaing of question by doing this `if d[item] > k:`

Comment: Do note the change in flag assignment. Also change the question to add expected output if you would like to get "exact" answers that can help.

Comment: Here is the question https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-with-at-least-k-repeating-characters/

Answer (score 0):

**To start with there is no problem of scope.**

Now lets get back to the problem
Lets define a rule.

> Rule:   If a sub string has each character repeated more than k(=2) times in it. Then it is a good substring.  Else it is a bad substring

Then your code simply prints the length of good sub string or 0 in case of bad substring

In short in your example string s= "ababbc"  contains no good substring
if you try S = "aaaaaa" you will see many numbers printed other than 0  (exactly 11 0's and 10 other numbers)

Now either this was your confusion or you wrote the wrong code for some logic
I hope this helps

Comment: No, it contains a good substring. My question is to find a substring which has all the character greater than or equal to k. question is from here https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-with-at-least-k-repeating-characters/

s= "ababbc" has "ababb" where all the character in substring is equal to or greater thank. The problem is that anything in this block `if flag == 1:`is 0.

Comment: @vivek should i give u an easier answer. would that be acceptable